# Как создавать собственные типы объектов в openstreatmap

Tags: javascript, map

Как используя следующую библиотеку, я могу создать собственный типо объекта (точки) на карте openstreatmap, https://github.com/openstreetmap/id-tagging-schema. iD editor за пушем локально